# addFileAttachmentAsync() produces attachment that I cannot view/open

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, office-js, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I'm creating an Outlook add-in, and i'm attempting to attach documents into a compose email through the add-in. Im using the addFileAttachmentAsync() method. Here is my code:

```
Office.context.mailbox.item.addFileAttachmentAsync(
    url,
    docName,
    function (asyncResult) {
        if (asyncResult.status == Office.AsyncResultStatus.Succeeded) {
            // Get the ID of the attached file.
            var attachmentID = asyncResult.value;
        }
    });
```

The result of this call is successful, because i'm able to get the attachment id of the result.
However, im not able to open the attached document. For example, when trying to open a docx document, I get the error `Word found unreadable content in _____.`
And similarly in outlook in chrome, I get the error `Sorry, we ran into a problem while opening this document.`

I don't get any errors when running the code, but when opening the file I get the error:

`Access to XMLHttpRequest at https://browser.pipe.aria.microsoft.com/ping from origin https://euc-word-view.officeapps.live.com has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.`

Comment: [Cross Posted](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/665) Could you provide a version number to help us understand the environment to reproduce this? You can get the version number by calling the api `Office.context.mailbox.diagnostics.hostVersion`. When the callback for the API is invoked, what is the result that is returned?

Comment: Not sure if the manifest file's AppDomains has any impact to this - the attachment URLs that we use point back to our service, which is same domain as where the Outlook App files is sourced from.  Did you save the file and look at the actual contents to see if it is intact word docx (basically a zip) or an HTML error response?  Note that the attachment is being retrieved by the back-end Exchange / O365 server if you are using web browser, or directly if you use Outlook.

Comment: Does the behavior change depending on the type of client you use?  If you are supplying a URL to a cloud URL, there could be other issues like this one: https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/322